# How to create a folded map in monotouch iPhone like what is in map application of iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

This is a screen shot of map application of iPhone:

[image]

How we can implement shuch page in our application. I am a new on iphone and monotouch and don't know whether this is a component that give the availability o folding or a feature on the MKMapView? Or maybe it is a custom code!
Can any body help me about this?

Comment: check my edited answer please, and dont forget to check my answer as the correct one if it helps you so i can get credit for it.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code snippet and it will do the job.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:urImage 
    duration:1.5 
    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
    animations^{
        urImage.frame = requiredFrame;
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        //[urImage removeFromSuperview];
        // do something after animation has completed
    }
   ];
```

You can play around with it and plug it where want.

And her is the link to apple's doc's for the uiview animation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Edit:

here is a set of codes that is going to give you the same effect: just hook up the inactions properly. it only uses couple of buttons to curl up and curl down so you should be able to do it. just create a single view app and place two buttons in the view and hook up the actions to the right button and there you go.:)

code for .h file:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIView *viewSecond;
IBOutlet UIView *viewFirst;   
}

- (IBAction)btnSecondView_Clicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnFirstView_Clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

code for .m file:

```
 #import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)btnSecondView_Clicked:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[viewSecond setAlpha:0.0];
[viewFirst setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:viewSecond cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];   
}

- (IBAction)btnFirstView_Clicked:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[viewFirst setAlpha:0.0];   
[viewSecond setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:viewFirst cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

hope this will help you take of business.

happy coding.:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'm really a new one on iPhone and also don't similar with Objective-C. can you introduce me a sample that contains this code. it will help a lot